# WP-CLI :: Cannot installing plugin as www-data

Tags: wp-cli

Just started using WP-CLI and instead of running with `--allow-root`, decided to run as `www-data` user. Things are good so far but cannot install any plugin that way at all:

```
root@wp-ks320:/var/www/ks320# sudo -u www-data wp plugin install hello-dolly
Installing Hello Dolly (1.6)
Warning: Could not create directory.
Downloading install package from https://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/hello-dolly.1.6.zip...
Unpacking the package...
#
root@wp-ks320:/var/www/ks320# sudo -u www-data -- wp plugin status hello-dolly
Error: The 'hello-dolly' plugin could not be found.
```

It's keep saying `Could not create directory` but creating directory as `www-data` is not really a problem:

```
root@wp-ks320:/var/www/ks320# sudo -u www-data -- mkdir wp-content/testDir
root@wp-ks320:/var/www/ks320# ls -l wp-content|grep test
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data     4096 Nov 15 22:58 testDir
```

If I use `wp --allow-root plugin install hello-dolly` instead, it works just fine but created the directory as `root` for obvious reason. What am I missing here or doing wrong? Best!

Answer (score 2):

Based on the issue you've reported and preview of the shell bash, it looks as if you may have the wrong owner/group and permissions set for the website's docroot.

More than likely in your hosting environment, the entire ks320 directory currently does not have www-data as the group assignment.

It can be owned by root but should be assigned to the www-data group (recursively).  Running an `ls -l` from the `/var/www` directory will output the current permissions, owner, and group assignments to each file and folder.

It probably resembles

```
drwr-xr-x  ###  root  root  ###   DATE   FILE_OR_FOLDER_NAME
```

but should resemble:

```
drwrwxr-x  ###  root  www-data  ###   DATE   FILE_OR_FOLDER_NAME
```

You can accomplish changing the group assignment from the `/var/www` directory with the following command:

```
chown -R root:www-data ks320
```

Then, you'll also want to make sure the group has read/write/execute permissions on the directory.  You can accomplish this from the `/var/www` directory with:

```
chmod -R 775 ks320
```

Once the permissions and group assignments to the folders have been set, your "www-data" user should be able to create the plugin directory and unzip the wordpress plugin files into place.

[For more about recommended permissions for a Wordpress site's files and folders, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions)